# Azure Devops Stale Pull Requests

Tags: azure-devops

You can connect Azure Devops with Microsoft Teams to send notifications on new pull requests (or completed, etc). Is there a way to warn for pull requests that are still open after 4 weeks? I don't see it in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#git.pullrequest.created)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. But you can try to use azure devops itself for this purpose.

To achieve this you need

- create cron pipeline
- fetch all active pull request (you can use azure CLI)
- filter those opened for 4 weeks
- push info to MS Teams via webhook about those PR's